# Drawing personage on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a basic technical test for a HTML5 game. It will be a background on a canvas, and the personage will move to the click position. I'm getting mad, because nothing is been rendered, not the background nor the personage. Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var contx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        canvas.width = 400;
        canvas.height = 300;

        var bgLoaded = false;
        var tgLoaded = false;

        var bgImage = new Image();

        bgImage.onload = function () {
            bgLoaded = true;
        };

        bgImage.src = "./maptest.png";
        var tgImage = new Image();
        tgImage.onload = function () {
            tgLoaded = true;
        };

        tgImage.src = "./testguy.png";

        var testguy = {
            speed: 256,
            x_pos: 0,
            y_pos: 0
        };

        canvas.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

        function getClickPosition(e) {
            var parentPosition = getPosition(e.currentTarget);
            var xPosition = e.clientX - parentPosition.x;
            var yPosition = e.clientY - parentPosition.y;

            testguy.x_pos = xPosition;
            testguy.y_pos = yPosition;
            contx.drawImage(tgImage, testguy.x_pos, testguy.y_pos);
        }

        function getPosition(element) {
            var xPosition = 0;
            var yPosition = 0;

            while (element) {
                xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
                yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
                element = element.offsetParent;
            }
            return {
                x: xPosition,
                y: yPosition
            };
        }

        function renderEngine() {
            if (bgLoaded === true) {
                contx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
            }
            if (tgLoaded === true) {
                contx.drawImage(tgImage, testguy.x_pos, testguy.y_pos);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't append your canvas to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

A few glitches:

- Append your canvas to the DOM (as @Derek says)
- Let your images fully load before trying to draw them
- When drawing your person, clear the canvas and redraw the background & the person.

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Qsq85/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var contx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        var testguy,bgImage,tgImage;

        // this code will preload all images and then call the start() function
        var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
        var imagesOK=0;
        var imgs=[];
        imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/SPback.png");
        imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/marioSmall.png");
        loadAllImages(start);

        function loadAllImages(callback){
            for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
                var img = new Image();
                imgs.push(img);
                img.onload = function(){ 
                    imagesOK++; 
                    if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                        callback();
                    }
                };
                img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
                img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
                img.src = imageURLs[i];
            }      
        }

        function start(){

            // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images

            // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

            bgImage=imgs[0];
            tgImage=imgs[1];

            canvas.width=bgImage.width;
            canvas.height=bgImage.height;

            contx.drawImage(bgImage,0,0);

            testguy = {
                speed: 256,
                x_pos: 0,
                y_pos: 0
            };

            canvas.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

        }

        function getClickPosition(e) {
            var parentPosition = getPosition(e.currentTarget);
            var xPosition = e.clientX - parentPosition.x;
            var yPosition = e.clientY - parentPosition.y;

            testguy.x_pos = xPosition;
            testguy.y_pos = yPosition;

            contx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            contx.drawImage(bgImage,0,0);
            contx.drawImage(tgImage, testguy.x_pos, testguy.y_pos);
        }

        function getPosition(element) {
            var xPosition = 0;
            var yPosition = 0;

            while (element) {
                xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
                yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
                element = element.offsetParent;
            }
            return {
                x: xPosition,
                y: yPosition
            };
        }

        function renderEngine() {
            if (bgLoaded === true) {
                contx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
            }
            if (tgLoaded === true) {
                contx.drawImage(tgImage, testguy.x_pos, testguy.y_pos);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```